# Switching form is not working in CRM 2013

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a script on CRM 2011 which is change the form based on the field value. The script is as below.

```
Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get(TypedFormID).navigate()
```

TypedFormID is the ID of the form. This was working fine with CRM 2011 but once it is upgraded the form is not able to change. I cant get any error but CRM not able to change the form. I have also debug the script but i dont get any error.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working fine now. This may be some temporary issue in microsoft CRM.

Answer (score 1):

The code still works for me fine in my CRM 2013 deployment migrated from CRM 2011.

I believe that you have an issue with id of a form. It should be without brackets {, } and all letters should be in lowercase.